# Android - Loading picture from web no longer working

Tags: android, url, imageview, drawable

I have code that i was copying from another project that will allow you to pass it a url and it will return a picture...then you set it to an image view and it will display the picture...but somewhere down the line...it isn't displaying the retrieved picture anymore...can you guys look at this code and tell me if there is something wrong???

CLICK EVENT

```
void NextPic(View v)
{
    picNum++; //int holding what pic number we are on
    Drawable bPic = LoadImageFromWebOperations(picData[]); //picData = String[] with url data in it
    imgView.setImageDrawable(bPic); //Cast earlier in the code
}
```

Get Pic Function

```
private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
{
    try
    {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
        return d;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Custom error handler
        uu.SendError(e.getMessage(), "Main.GetPickTask.LoadImageFromWeboperations(String url)");
        return null;
    }
}
```

LogCat shows nothing at all...there are no error caught...and the pic keeps coming up blank...i even used the ic_launcher graphic as a placeholder so see if it was the imageview itself...but that shows up for a few seconds and then goes black

Here is an example URL i am using
http://app.guycothal.com/Funnys/2012722133515231.jpg

Comment: are you calling it from the ui thread? perhaps your new project is of newer API level which does not allow you to make network operations on main thread. Also your method is expecting a `String` and you seem to be trying to send it a `String[]` I am surprised if what you've pasted here even compiles.

Comment: @Tim: It work on another project...in fact 90% of the code from this project is copied from the working project...the only this changed was the menus and the theme...i am calling it from an `AsyncTask`...but the code i posted was outside the `AsyncTask` so i could rule that out completely

Comment: no clue what i did...but it is working now...thats for you help @Tim

Answer (score 0):

```
    private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```